# get rel from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here Html given below

```
 <div class="navBulletsWrapper">
<div rel="0" class=""></div>
<div rel="1" class=""></div>
<div rel="2" class=""></div>
<div rel="3" class=""></div>
<div rel="4" class="active"></div>
<div rel="5" class=""></div>
<div rel="6" class=""></div>
<div rel="7" class=""></div>
</div>
```

i want to get rel value of div having **class active**

tried

```
$('.navBulletsWrapper .active')[0].attr('rel')
```

but  fails because div doesn`t have attr

Comment: You should see the `docs` this is just a very easy thing to do, if you go through the `docs` you can find your answers. Although same questions had been asked here you can see the answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.navBulletsWrapper .active')[0]` will give you a **DOM** object, not a jquery object; thus, it won't have any jquery function like `attr` attached to it.

```
$('.navBulletsWrapper .active').eq(0).attr('rel')
```

should work.

if you only have one `.active` div at a time, you dont have to use `eq(0)`

```
$('.navBulletsWrapper .active').attr('rel')
```

Comment: thanks bro for giving solution of  one silly mistake  i have taken. marking it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

### http://jsfiddle.net/4dTAG/

The javascript only method would be as follows:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("navBulletsWrapper")[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].className=="active"){
        var rel = divs[i].attributes.rel.value;
        alert(rel);
        break;
    }
}
```

the jquery method going on with the method you have tried
http://jsfiddle.net/4dTAG/1/

```
var rel = $('.navBulletsWrapper .active')[0].attributes.rel.value
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the [0] as there is only one .active

```
$('.navBulletsWrapper .active').attr('rel');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.navBulletsWrapper .active')[0]
```

is an html element.

```
$('.navBulletsWrapper .active').eq(0)
```

is an jQuery element which has the `attr()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Native: 
    `document.querySelector('.navBulletsWrapper .active').getAttribute('rel');`

jQuery: 
    `$('.navBulletsWrapper .active').attr('rel');`

Answer (score 1):

`rel` attribute cannot be used with div according to documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel

It is better to use `data-id="1"` type attributes